# how to adding border to checkbox which is using png

Tags: android, border, android-drawable

Having defined drawable with given png for each items in the drawable for different states, if want to having border around the png for that item, how to do it? re-cut the png is not option here.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/box_checked_png” />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/white_box_png” />
<item android:state_checked="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/white_box_png” />
<item android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/box_checked_png” />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method which i find best is to add a background to the check box.

This is a  rectangle drawable background.xml (put into res/drawable folder).
Let's say you are making a shape like this one :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

And where you have your check box, you just set the background made before:

```
<CheckBox android:text="Some me" android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

Comment: thanks Calin! If the drawable has 'checked' state to show the box_checked_png.